# how to show error message when execute mdx query in pentaho BI

Tags: mdx, pentaho, business-intelligence, saiku

I'm using Saiku Analytics, when i run MDX Query and the Query error , the error message is always

> Error executing query. Please check the server logs or contact your administrator!

[image: Error executing query. Please check the server logs or contact your administrator!]

How to get specific error message ? Then I can fix my query.

Or should I use another tool ?

Comment: Well, did you check [the server logs](http://wiki.meteorite.bi/display/SAIK/Log+Files)?

Comment: i cant find the server logs , im using Pentaho BI Server CE 6 with Saiku Analytics Plugin.

Comment: In the link I provided there is a exact location for the server logs. Where did you check? Which paths?